# How to show shipping address along billing address in order emails woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

In Woocommerce Version 3.6.4 I am getting order emails with only Billing address. I am trying to show shipping address along the billing address. but its not displaying. How to do that?

I tried following code in functions file.

*add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_needs_shipping_address', '__return_true' );*

but its not showing shipping address in email.

Comment: This thread might be of use, though it hasn't concluded yet: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/22493

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Let me try this.